# Finding possible sum combination of values for other 3 values

Tags: java

I need to find possible sum combination of values for 3 other values.

For example: numbers X=[a=50,b=30,c=20] and I need to find a, b and c considering A=[a=80,b=10,c=12], B=[a=15,b=0,c=9] and C=[a=1,b=22,c=4].

So, a solution would be

**R=[(Aa=34 + Ba=15 + Ca=1), (Ab=9 + Bb=0 + Cb=21), (Ac=10 + Bc=9 + Cc=1)]** satisfying **X=[a=50,b=30,c=20]**.

At the end

**A=[a=46,b=1,c=2]**

**B=[a=0, b=0, c=0]**

**C=[a=0, b=1, c=3]**

There is no need of using the value reaching 0. How can I do it? Is it possible?

Comment: Xa is the value I need to achieve with Aa, Ba, Ca, Xb is the value I need to achieve with Ab, Bb, Cb and Xc is the value I need to achieve with Ac, Bc, Cc. Simultaneously, sorry if I made it hard to understand. Hope it is clear now. At the end I just showed values left in A, B and C.

Comment: Xa, Xb and Xc values are arbitrary. I need to get Xa given combinations of Aa, Ba and Ca. Same for Xb with Ab, Bb, Cb and Xc... To make it simple, I only have A, B and C to get the ideia of how it works. The result in R is an example of solution. See @Eritrean answer, it is just what I expected. I don't think it is that hard to understand even after this two explanations... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a fixed number of elements to generate the desired combinations, a simple straight forward approach could be just to use a nested for-loop. See below example as a starting point:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // set up 
        List<Integer> x = List.of(50, 30, 20);

        List<Integer> a = List.of(80, 10, 12);
        List<Integer> b = List.of(15,  0,  9);
        List<Integer> c = List.of( 1, 22,  4);

        // generate combinations iterating over the range [0 - n] for each index of a,b and c 
        // and filter those whose sum is equal to the element of x at the corrsponding index
        List<List<Integer>> xa = generateCombinations(a.get(0), b.get(0), c.get(0), x.get(0));
        List<List<Integer>> xb = generateCombinations(a.get(1), b.get(1), c.get(1), x.get(1));
        List<List<Integer>> xc = generateCombinations(a.get(2), b.get(2), c.get(2), x.get(2));

        // combine the above combinations by adding each possible triplett into a list
        List<List<List<Integer>>> result = generateResultCombs(xa, xb, xc);

        result.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static List<List<List<Integer>>> generateResultCombs(
            List<List<Integer>> xa, List<List<Integer>> xb, List<List<Integer>> xc) {

        List<List<List<Integer>>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (List<Integer> combA : xa) {
            for (List<Integer> combB : xb) {
                for (List<Integer> combC : xc) {
                    result.add(List.of(combA, combB, combC));
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static List<List<Integer>> generateCombinations(int a, int b, int c, int x) {

        List<List<Integer>> combinations = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j <= b; j++){
                for (int k = 0; k <= c; k++){
                    if (i + j + k == x){
                        combinations.add(List.of(i, j, k));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return combinations;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for, this for-chain was killing me and I wasn't capable of figuring this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I offer the following Optimization to [@Eritrean's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73040682/1552534) `generateCombinations` method.

- first, all that is required is to use two nested loops. The sum of `i` and `j` can be subtracted from `x` to see if it lies within the range of `[0,c]`.
- second, the limit of each loop should depend on the minimum value of `x` as compared to `a` or `b`.  If `a = 80` and `x = 50`, there is no need to iterate to `80` as any value past `50` exceeds the target sum (negative values are not considered part of valid solutions).

Here is the method.

```
private static List<List<Integer>> generateCombinationsOpt(int a,
        int b, int c, int x) {
    List<List<Integer>> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
    int aLimit = Math.min(a, x);
    int bLimit = Math.min(b, x);
    for (int i = 0; i <= aLimit; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= bLimit; j++) {
            int d = x - (i + j);
            if (d >= 0 && d <= c) {
                combinations.add(List.of(i, j, d));
            }
        }
        
    }
    return combinations;
}
```

**Note:**  Ideally one would like to use the smaller two values of `a`, `b`, and `c` as the initial limits of the loops to further reduce the number of iterations.  But this would require extra bookkeeping to ensure that the resultant lists are properly populated.